# django how to save html with img tag to database

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a fresh graduate and currently writing my personal blog and want to do all the features by myself.

I have a `post.html` that dynamically displays a specified post content based on the `post_id`. This template will load the data (html format) that I save in the database.

In the database, I save the post content as html. When I load the post content, I use `{{ post.post_content | safe }}` in the `template.html`.

It works fine with text. I can get it display as I wanted. However, I fail to get the `img` display.

The img tag in my html looks like this:

```
<a href="{% static 'assets/img/blog/post1.png'%}" class="image-popup">
    <img src="{% static 'assets/img/blog/post1.png'%}" alt="Post Image">
</a>
```

Django fail to get the image url so the image cannot be displayed.

May I ask are there solutions for me to do this? Except asking me to put the actual/direct image url to the field.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So are you asking about _saving to db_ or about _using static files_?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes Ivan. The above lines of code are parts of the post_content. I save them in the db but when I call {{ post.post_content| safe}}, the app fails to read the image. The reason why the app fails to load the image is because the app treats it as HTML rather than "Django-based" code. I don't know how to solve it.